# webmatrix user id stored as -1 sometimes

Tags: webmatrix

I am developing a website using Webmatrix. I have a post page where user can post an item with several fields like item name, description, user name, phone number etc. I take all these values and save the item in database. Alongwith all this data provided by the user, I also save a user id of the user with WebSecurity.CurrentUserId method for that item. 
This works well almost everytime. However, on very few occasions, I noticed that user id is stored as "-1" for some items. 
I am absolutely clueless and can't figure out why it's happening.
Has someone ever experienced such thing. Or can someone may have clue about this?

Comment: It sounds like it is perhaps a problem in your program, generating values you don't expect sometimes (*maybe*), the problem is, you need to provide more information. Are you using "IsIdentity" for the id field?

Comment: Actually -1 is given when the user is logged out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain this will solve your problem but it would not hurt to verify that the current user is also defined within your web security database with WebSecurity.HasUserId property. I would give that a try - let me know what happens.

Hope that does the trick!